# Calculate the size of a page table

Tags: operating-system

An homeword question:

> Given system with 32 bit virtual addresses and 16 bit physical addresses.
>
> Assume that a page size is 1K.
>
> Calculate the size of the page table.

truly I have no idea how to start so I ask here for hint and directions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surely you have a book or notes on the subject? Homework is usually meant to test what you've seen in class.

Comment: Sadly, the homework question is rather nonsensical.It does not state how the addresses are divided (kernel v. user); the size of a page table entry; and the number of entries. If you were to assume 4-bytes as the entry size and that the table could describe the entire addresses space then your table size would need 32 - 10 bits = (22 bits entries). Thus your table would exceed the size of the physical address space. That's possible but not very practicable.